# How do I customize the text of the select options in the api browser?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using rest_framework v3.1.3 in django 1.8.  I am pretty new to django.

Here are the relevant model definitions

```
    @python_2_unicode_compatible
class UserFitbit(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='fituser')
    fitbit_user = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    auth_token = models.TextField()
    auth_secret = models.TextField()

    #this is a hack so that I can use this as a lookup field in the serializers
    @property
    def user__userid(self):
        return self.user.id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name

    def get_user_data(self):
        return {
            'user_key': self.auth_token,
            'user_secret': self.auth_secret,
            'user_id': self.fitbit_user,
            'resource_owner_key': self.auth_token,
            'resource_owner_secret': self.auth_secret,
            'user_id': self.fitbit_user,
        }

    def to_JSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, 
            sort_keys=True, indent=4)



class Challenge(models.Model):
    name=models.TextField()
    status=models.TextField() #active, pending, ended, deleted
    start_date=models.DateField()
    end_date=models.DateField()
    #members=models.ManyToManyField(UserFitbit)
    members=models.ManyToManyField(User)
    admin=models.ForeignKey(UserFitbit,related_name='admin')

    #for each member get stats between the start and end dates
    def memberstats(self):
        stats = [] 
        for member in self.members.all():
            fbu = UserFitbit.objects.filter(user__id=member.id)
            fu = UserData.objects.filter(userfitbit=fbu)
            fu = fu.filter(activity_date__range=[self.start_date,self.end_date])
            fu = fu.annotate(first_name=F('userfitbit__user__first_name'))
            fu = fu.annotate(user_id=F('userfitbit__user__id'))
            fu = fu.annotate(last_name=F('userfitbit__user__last_name'))
            fu = fu.values('first_name','last_name','user_id')
            fu = fu.annotate(total_distance=Sum('distance'),total_steps=Sum('steps'))
            if fu:
                stats.append(fu[0])
        return stats

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Challenge:' + str(self.name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-start_date','name')
```

And here is the serializer for the challenge

```
class ChallengeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  links = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
  memberstats = MemberStatSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)
  #these are user objects
  #this should provide a hyperlink to each member
  members = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    #queryset defines the valid selectable values 
    queryset=User.objects.all(),
    view_name='user-detail',
    lookup_field='pk',
    many=True, 
  )

  class Meta:
    model=Challenge
    fields = ('id','name','admin','status','start_date','end_date','members','links','memberstats',)
    read_only_fields = ('memberstats','links',)


  def get_links(self, obj) :
    request = self.context['request']
    return {
      'self': reverse('challenge-detail',
        kwargs={'pk':obj.pk},request=request),
    }
```

As you can see the Challenge has a many to many relationship with User. This is the built in User model from django not UserFitBit defined here.

With these definitions when I go to the api browser for a challenge I need to be able to select the users based on their name, but the select only shows their User id property and the hyperlink url.  I would like the members to be User objects, but I don't know how to change the text for the select options since I don't think I can change the built in User object. What is the best way to change the select box options to show the users name from the User object rather than the username field and hyperlink?

Here is an image:
[image]

Comment: There's now an open ticket for improving this: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/3254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but after reading DRF's source code, I would try this.

Subclass the `HyperlinkedRelatedField` and override the `choices` property.

```
import six
from collections import OrderedDict

class UserHyperLinkedRelatedField(serializers.HyperLinkedRelatedField):

    @property
    def choices(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if queryset is None:
            return {}

        return OrderedDict([
            (
                six.text_type(self.to_representation(item)),
                six.text_type(item.get_full_name())
            )
            for item in queryset
        ])
```

then would simply replace the field in the serializer.

```
members = UserHyperlinkedRelatedField(
    queryset=User.objects.all(),
    view_name='user-detail',
    lookup_field='pk',
    many=True, 
)
```

The DRF docs also mentioned that there's a plan to add a public API to support customising HTML form generation in future releases.

**Update**

For DRF 3.2.2 or higher, there will be an available `display_value` method.

You can do

```
class UserHyperLinkedRelatedField(serializers.HyperLinkedRelatedField):

    def display_value(self, instance):
        return instance.get_full_name()
```

Comment: Accepted because this led me to the solution. I also needed to subclass the ManyRelatedField to make it work in this situation. I Posted my code in another answer in case anyone else comes across this

Answer (score 1):

Because this is a many related field I also had to extend the ManyRelatedField and override the many_init method of the RelatedField to use that class. Can't say I understand all of this just yet, but it is working.

```
class UserManyRelatedField(serializers.ManyRelatedField):

    @property
    def choices(self):
        queryset = self.child_relation.queryset
        iterable = queryset.all() if (hasattr(queryset, 'all')) else queryset
        items_and_representations = [
            (item, self.child_relation.to_representation(item))
            for item in iterable
        ]
        return OrderedDict([
            (
                six.text_type(item_representation),
                item.get_full_name() ,
            )
            for item, item_representation in items_and_representations
        ])


class UserHyperlinkedRelatedField(serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField):

    @classmethod
    def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        list_kwargs = {'child_relation': cls(*args, **kwargs)}
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            if key in MANY_RELATION_KWARGS:
                list_kwargs[key] = kwargs[key]
        return UserManyRelatedField(**list_kwargs)


members = UserHyperlinkedRelatedField(
    queryset=User.objects.all(),
    view_name='user-detail',
    lookup_field='pk',
    many=True, 
)
```